# MVVM Light DispatcherHelper in PCL

Tags: mvvm-light, portable-class-library

Is there a timeline when MVVM Light DispatcherHelper will be available for PCL? In the official blog there is only a remark, that it's not available at the moment.

Comment: Would also be interested to hear some news about prospects for this.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a nuget package that helps you call RaisePropertyChanged from the UI thread in MvvmLight PCLs.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sylapse.MainThreadDispatch

Just use `this.DispatchSet (() => MyProperty, ref _myProperty, value)` in your property set methods.

Only Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS supported so far. But UWP and other windows platforms will be added soon.